# Scale an image by a single dimension (x OR y) given minimum dimensions

Tags: python, image-scaling

I know I could do this with a bunch of nested if statements, however I can't help feel like there's a more elegant way. It's really just a maths issue I guess, but I'm interested in pythonic answers if indeed there are any.

I have an image which can be ANY dimensions / aspect ratio.

It must be scaled up OR down so that it covers a minumum of 55w x 168h

The complication here is that it needs to be scaled by a function that takes only a single value which specifies the length of a side of a square which the image it will fit inside.

For instance, say we have an image of size 1000w x 500h and we scale it to 200, then the resulting image must fit inside a square the with a side of 200, meaning the resulting image would be 200w x 100h.

Conversely if our image is 200x1000 and we scale to to 200, we'll end up with 40x200.

So to scale an image of 1000x500 to cover 55x168, we'd need to scale it to 336, giving a size of 336x168 since that's the largest image which can fit inside a 336x336 sided square.

And to scale an image of 200x1000 to cover 55x168, we'd need to scale it to 275 and end up with 55x275.

Hopefully this is clearer than mud! Thanks for any ideas.

**Justification:** For those who are interested in why I'm scaling via a value of a square side, this is the way Picasa scales images via URL injection. For instance take the following 2 URLs:

- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-rvkbjZgBMDs/UEHYD3VmGVI/AAAAAAAADwM/UekknfI838s/s150/IMG_20120901_172419.jpg
- https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6BHPw9kYIQc/UEHYBS5z-dI/AAAAAAAADwA/QkEWF3H797A/s150/IMG_20120901_172405.jpg

Notice both have the URL component `s150`, however one image is 150x112 and the other is 112x150. 150 is the value of the square these images will both fit in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def name_of_function(img_x, img_y):  # for lack of a better name
    image_dimensions = (img_x, img_y)
    min_dimensions = (55.0, 168.0)
    scale = min(image_dimensions[i]/min_dimensions[i] for i in range(2))
    return max(i/scale for i in image_dimensions)

name_of_function(1000, 500)
# 336.0
name_of_function(200, 1000)
# 275.0
```

Pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to say more about the particulars, but I'll assume the function has access either to the image or to its dimensions, otherwise the computation is not possible.

But that in hand, something like this ought to work:

```
def percent_to_scale_to(image, box_side_px):
    img_width, img_height = Image(image).size()  # or however you get w/h
    greater_img_dimension = max(img_width, img_height)
    scale_percent = (float(box_side_px) / float(greater_img_dimension)) * 100.0
```

You'll likely need to look up the signatures of some of the calls, and don't expect it to just work with a cut-and-paste, but as pseudo-code perhaps it gives you an idea for an approach. :)

You'll want to look out for integer division, which might produce unexpected behaviors. That's why the conversion to float before the division; otherwise the result is truncated at the decimal point which could produce a return value of zero most of the time. Some quick research on Python's division behavior will likely be worthwhile if you're not already familiar.

Comment: Sorry you're right I probably should have explained my inputs a bit better, however the other answer has nailed it :)